# Can I "properly" merge branches that have been merged with --no-ff

Tags: git

I have a branch called 'main' with the latest release and one called 'staging' with the next feature to be released. Staging will normally be ahead of main, so doing a "reintegration" merge (i.e. merging staging into main) would normally be a fast-forward, which is what I want.

However, at some point in the past, the branches have been merged with `--no-ff` so I now have two parallel branches which are exact copies of each other but with different commit hashes, so my merges can never FF.

Is there a way to recombine them so they point to the same commit hash without doing `reset --hard` and `push --force` ? For some reason, github won't let me do a force push. I'm not interested in rewriting history; I just want to converge the two branches going forward.

Comment: Merge one into the other.... then you can merge _back_ and it will be a FF and you will be back at your happy place where both branches are pointing to the same commit.... that is, if you use _plain ol' git_. Don't make promises about what providers might.... _provide_.

Comment: Side note. The answer to your question is clear. However, since you stated, "I have a branch called 'main' with the latest release", I would consider still using `--no-ff` instead of fast-forward so that the first-parent history on `main` shows you what was released and when. This is a great use case for `--no-ff`. Even if you continue to use `--no-ff`, I'd still merge `main` into `staging` to get it up to date. In fact I would do that after every merge of `staging` into `main` so that it's always fully up-to-date.

Comment: It might be better to change your expectations. Different branches _should_ point to different commits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you merge two branches, one branch will be *ahead* of the other branch, and the other branch will be *behind* of the first branch. If one branch is only ahead (and not *diverged*), you can simply fast-forward to it.

```
...a-b-c           < branch1
    /
...m-n-o           < branch2
```

You first do your regular merge (`git checkout branch1 && git merge branch2`):

```
...a-b-c-d         < branch1
    /   /
...m-n-o           < branch2
```

And then fast-forward the other branch (`git checkout branch2 && git merge branch1`):

```
...a-b-c-d         < branch1, branch2
    /   /
...m-n-o
```

Nothing needs to be reset, rebased, rewritten, or anything of that sort and you should be able to push cleanly without any problem.

Comment: Yes you're completely correct - I thought I had tried this but obviously what I'd done was something different. I can't find a way to delete the question so I have marked this as the answer

Comment: @Andy It's still valid question. Just because the problem has been solved for you doesn't mean the question should be deleted. Future visitors might have the same or a similar question and will be happy to already find it asked and answered.